# Is there a way to set `margin` values for ph_location object in officeR package?

Tags: powerpoint, margin, officer

I need to adjust the textbox margin values for items created using code like the following:

```
label_par <- fpar(
    ftext("test", fp_text(bold = FALSE, font.size = 5, font.family = 'Arial')),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center")
)
label_location <- ph_location(
    left = 0.5, top = 2, 
    width = 0.23, height = .0.22, 
    rotation = 0
)
ph_with(presentation_obj, label_par, label_location)
```

I tried setting the default textbox shape in my PPT template to have the margin values that I want. However, since officeR creates placeholder content boxes, they don't adhere to the same defaults as the textbox shapes.

Is there a way that I can adjust the margins for the ph_location objects?

I tried passing `margin = 0` into `ph_location`, but as the documentation describes, the `...` arguments are not used.